# Unhandled promise rejection when iterating over async calls before awaiting all

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I've encountered a weird problem I cant find an explanation to anywhere.
In the following code, I'm trying to get a number of `position` entities, each by id using and API call.

Some id requests might end up with an 404, and I dont mind that, that's why I'm using `Promise.allSettled()`

```
    const positionsPromises = idList.map((id) => {
      return this.positionRepository.getPositionById(id);
    });

    const positions = await Promise.allSettled(positionsPromises);
```

This generally works, but for non-existing ids (or any other errors), I get the famous node logs for `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

however... when taking the same `.map()` code and just throwing it directly inside `Promise.allSettled()` I get no such things, and it works as expected- some resolve, some reject, and I can iterate over `positions` to check each one.

```
    const positions = await Promise.allSettled(
      idList.map((id) => {
        return this.positionRepository.getPositionById(id);
      }),
    );
```

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong here with returning an array of pending Promises before awaiting them all?

Comment: This is because you're awaiting a promise without handling the error even though you're using allSettled, try surrounding it with a try/catch

Comment: @KhaledOsman the OP is fairly obviously already aware of that. He's asking why the second example doesn't produce that error while the first does

Comment: @BenWainwright Thanks, yeah using `allSettled` already handles the error for you as the result will include the status of these promises and whether they were fulfilled or rejected

Comment: So, any further ideas as to why what I described happens?